# Change permalink for a single post entry

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've defined a custom post type, `projects`, and I've set the permalink for those post types to `/projects/my-project/`. 
However, for one of the projects, I need to give it a special URL, so instead of `/projects/special-project/` it appears on `/special-project/`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `functions.php`:

```
function wpse221475_custom_rewrite_rules() {

  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^(special-project)?', 
    'index.php?post_type=projects&name=$matches[1]', 
    'top'
  );

}

add_action('init', 'wpse221475_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

Make sure to flush your rewrite rules after adding this rule.

Visit:

`Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks`

Or if you wish, you can use [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) programmatically.

To redirect requests for `http://example.com/projects/special-project` to `http://example.com/special-project` you can parse the request on the `wp` hook.

```
function wpse221475_redirect_request($wp) {

    if ( ! empty($wp->request) && $wp->request === 'projects/special-project' ) {

        wp_redirect(home_url('special-project'), 301);
        exit;

    }

}

add_action('wp', 'wpse221475_redirect_request');
```

Of course there are other ways/methodologies you could use to achieve the same effect but the above will suffice.

Comment: This is partially working, so when I go to `my-site.com/special-project/`, the right content is rendered. 

But the problem is that I can still see the same content in `my-site.com/projects/special-project/`. Also, the latter URL is the one appearing as the "canonical" URL even for `my-site.com/special-project/`. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct behaviour. You have to forcible parse the request and redirect away to your target destination. See my update for additional code.

Comment: I was missing the canonical, but I managed to do it hooking into `post_type_link`. With that, you don't even need the redirect (the "standard" url had never been publicly exposed)